# How do I send a request to the application layer for a specific file (keep in mind we are using WCF and data contracts)?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, datacontract

We are using WCF and Data contracts - I am not understanding how to send a request to the application layer for a specific set of data. I want to get data for a file, but I can't get it. It is not http or Webrequest either. Please help.

I have tried Webrequest and many other options and there is nothing online to help. We are using an N-tier architecture and I am trying to figure out how to send requests to the application layer from the UI so that I can get the data sent back to me.

```
 // generate summary of the Project Selected, if it is index 0 (CNS 41) retrieve file from application layer
        // otherwise, retrieve the file for CJ74
        private void btnGenerateSummary_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            if(PMDropDown.SelectedItemIndex == 0)
            {
                //send request to application layer for CNS41
                SapFileInfo request = new SapFileInfo();
                SapFileInfo response = request.getResponse();

            }
            else
            {
                //send request to application layer for CJ74
            }
        }
```

I want to get a response from the application layer with the data from the database, which I will write into a file that will go into excel and I will format it using open XML 2.5.

Comment: Here's the documentation on how to call a WCF service. It's probably easiest to start with the section on [Add Service Reference in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client#add-service-reference-in-visual-studio).

Comment: I don't understand why you can't do this considering you are already using data contracts and have a working WCF setup.  The rest I would have thought be easy